# Magento 2 - images in store config (per radio button)

Tags: magento2, system-config

I have currently installed `Magento 2.3.x` and I want to create a `radio field` in system config with an image (please look at the screenshot below).

[image]

What is the best practice to do that? I am not so satisfied with my solution (images in base64). Where should I store images for module purposes? I need to distribute it with a module.

**Config definition:**

```
<field id="catalog" translate="label" type="radios" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
    <label>Catalog page design</label>
    <source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Config\Source\Foo</source_model>
</field>
```

**Source model code:**

```
<?php
    
    namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Config\Source;
    
    class Foo implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
    {
        public const IMG_CATALOG_BUTTON = 'data:image/png;base64, ..... ';
        /**
         * @inheritDoc
         */
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            return  [
                [
                    'value' => 'test',
                    'label' => __('Minimalistic variant') . " <img src='" . self::IMG_CATALOG_BUTTON . "' width='180' style='vertical-align: top;'>",
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 'production',
                    'label' => __('Page strip variant') . " <img src='" . self::IMG_CATALOG_BUTTON . "' width='180' style='vertical-align: top;'>",
                ],
            ];
        }
    }
```

Please can you help me with the best practices in M2? (I working many years with M1). Thanks!

Comment: I believe that best way to do it is use css pseudo element image